# Tries to validate when pressing logout button instead of submit

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my admin pages I've got a `"Log out"` button. On one page there's this form you can fill in and submit and it has some `validator controls`. The problem is that when I am on this page, I can't log out, because it wants the textboxes to be filled in, even though it's - obviously - not submitted via the log out button. Are the validators executing everytime you try to leave this page, even though I'm not trying to submit a form? To be clear: it works for every other page, it's just the validation here that stops it.

Form code:

```
<p>
        <asp:Label ID="lblA" runat="server" Text="LabelA"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtA" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        *

                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                    ID="rfvA"
                    runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="txtA"
                    ErrorMessage="Required"
                    Display="Dynamic">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="lblB" runat="server" Text="LabelB"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtB" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        *

                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
                    ID="rfvB"
                    runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="txtB"
                    ErrorMessage="Required"
                    Display="Dynamic">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </p>
```

Logout button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Log out" ID="btnLogout" OnClick="btnLogout_Click"/>
```

When Log out is clicked:

```
protected void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add cause validation false to your button

`<asp:Button runat="server" CausesValidation="False" Text="Log out" ID="btnLogout" OnClick="btnLogout_Click"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the `ValidationGroup` property of the controls.
Assign the same `ValidationGroup` to the group of controls(and `RequiredFieldValidator`) which you require for validation like username and password text boxes and login button(In your case to the two text boxes) and assign the different `ValidationGroup` to the other controls(In your case to logout button).

So the validation fires only when the same validation group's button has been clicked.